# Accessing Computer screen from android over WLAN

Tags: android

I have an extra router, is there an app or any way I can view my computer screen (windows 7) over my android over a network, **not WiFi**. All Apps out there require a internet, but I need to access it over a network only with no internet access

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. Please use other resources, like http://android.stackexchange.com, for non-programming Android questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple VNC clients for Android.  [This one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.androidVNC&hl=en) came up when I searched Google, but there are many more.

All you need network-wise is some way to access the VNC port on the server machine (the Windows 7 computer) from the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an app called Jump. You will also need to setup port forwarding on your vnc port of your pc.Typically 5900.